# Apply two custom fonts in a paragraph and display them in android

Tags: android, android-fonts

The project I worked on has some rare characters that are not supported by Unicode 
"private-use area" (PUA) code points in the range U+EE80 through U+EFF. One custom open type font range from U+0000 to U+FFFF and the other has characters beyond U+FFFF. Both fonts are in the same language.

I need to display the characters based on their PUA range(characters are retrieved from database in random lines, no fixed location for a particular character). I tried different solutions but none of them works(bidi class with typeface, composite fonts, merging fonts, fallback, etc).

Has somebody used custom fonts that can display different font based on their range of PUA code points(character by character) on Android?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java to develop your android app, java only support unicode system so you cannot use characters beyond unicode system.